# [fromly]: pass controller to template

Tags: angular-formly

I'm trying to make form with button inside js, because formly directive rendered form isn't correct. I decided push my button and render that button by template but button has lost access to the controller and validation form. Where i have missed here?

controller.js

```
.controller('X', ['$log', 'Api', function($log, Api) {
  var _self = this;

  _self.model = {};
  _self.formParts = [{
    className: 'row',
    fieldGroup: [
      {
        className: 'col-xs-3',
        key: 'q',
        type: 'select',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          valueProp: "id",
          labelProp: "name",
          options: [
            {name: '0', id: 0},
            {name: '1', id: 1},
          ],
        }
      },
      {
        className: 'col-xs-7',
        key: 'n',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'name'
        }
      }
      {
        className: 'col-xs-2',
        templateUrl: 'button.html'
      }
    ]
  }];
  _self.save(model) {
    $log.info(model);
  };
}]);
```

main.html

```
<formly-form model="f.model"
             fields="f.formFields"
             form="formForm">
</formly-form>
```

button.html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
        ng-disabled="formForm.$invalid"
        ng-click="f.save(f.model)">Save
</button>
```

Comment: This is a fundamental concept in angular-formly. You don't have access to your controller in the formly templates because formly templates are compiled with their own `$scope`. Please refer to the angular-formly learning material: http://learn.angular-formly.com

Comment: Also, I should mention that the best way to get help with angular-formly is providing an example of the trouble you're having in the form of a jsbin: http://help.angular-formly.com